# Dynamically evaluating statement with multiple equality operators

Tags: c#, eval

I've seen quite a few expression parsers / tokenizers that can take a certain string and evaluate the result.  For example, you could pump the string:

```
4+4
```

into the following code:

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
//' You always need to initialize a language engine
sc.Language = "VBScript";
//' this is the expression - in a real program it will probably be
//' read from a textbox control 
string  expr  = "4+4";
double res  = sc.Eval(expr);
```

and get 8.  But, is there a parsing tool out there that can evaluate the string:

```
4 = 4 = 4
```

?  So far, all examples fail with an error of not being able to compare a double and boolean (which makes sense from a compilers perspective, but from a human perspective, we can see that this is true).  Anyone come across something that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a human perspective, this is only true if we think of x = y = z as a special operator (with three operands), where it implies x = y, y = z, x = z.  That is a specific syntactical interpretation of the expression.  A human (particularly a programmer) could also interpret it the same way most compilers do, which is to choose the left-most grouping ( x = y ) and then compare the result of that comparison (a boolean value) to z.  Even to a human, this doesn't make sense under this syntax.  It only seems obvious from a human perspective because humans are notoriously fuzzy when it comes to choosing a syntax that 'makes sense' for a given context.

If you really want that level of 'fuzziness', you'll need to look into something like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%20=%204%20=%204), which performs contextual analysis to try to find a best guess for the meaning of the expression.  If you enter '4 = 4 = 4' there, it will reply True.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define syntax for your "language" and build parser as your expected behavior is not covered by normal expression syntax (and also normal languages should evaluate it to "false" as every language I heard of implements = as binary operation and hence will endup with "4 = true" at some point). There are tools to build parser for C#...

Side note: to match "a human perspective" is insanely hard problem still not solved even for human to human communication :).

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
var result = (int) HtmlPage.Window.Eval("4 + 4");
```

Comment: OP can already get it. Does your code return `true` for `4 = 4 = 4`?